# Mass URL parameter cleanup from txt file

Tags: python, bash, curl, wget

I have a url list file similar to

```
    Www.dell.com/any=abc&anyone=bcd
    Www.google.co.in 
    Www.yahoo.com/abc=fgh
```

I want to clean up then, as they show only data up to equal sign `=`. For example, the lines shown above should output

```
Www.dell.com/any=
Www.dell.com/any=abc&anyone=
Www.google.co.in 
Www.yahoo.com/abc=
```

Any script suggestions for code clean-up like this in python or bash etc?

Comment: Equal signs are important for query strings, and those have question marks. It's unclear what your ultimate goal is, but separating the keys and values seems like a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Script line-by-line using a regex which just adds the token #1 to the result file

Regex to get everything of a line till first =

```
^([^=]*=)
```

**EDIT** your 2nd example with several params doesn't exactly match the text, I focused on your text to remove everything after FIRST =
otherwise replace [^=] by . to get everything till the LAST =

Answer (score 0):

```
url = re.sub(r'^(.*?=).*$', r'\1', url)
```

This will give you url until first "=". Remove the "?" mark to get the url until last "=".

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through and strip the lines like so in Python.

```
for l in urls:
    print l.split('=')[0]
```